How to configure gRPC client in C# on .NET 8 to use http/3
I have a grpcServer configured to utilize HTTP/3 and it is verified that it is capable to serve HTTP/3:
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Configure Kestrel to use HTTP/3
        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ListenAnyIP(7227, listenOptions =>
            {
                // listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
                listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http3;
                listenOptions.UseHttps(@"X:\YYYYY\ZZZ\localhost.pfx", "SomePassword"); // Ensure HTTPS is used for HTTP/3
            });
        });

        // Configure logging
        builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
        builder.Logging.AddConsole();

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddGrpc();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
        app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var protocol = context.Request.Protocol;
            Console.WriteLine($"Protocol used: {protocol}");
            await next.Invoke();
        });

        app.Run();
    }
}

And I have a grpcClient configured to communicate with that server using HTTP/3:
internal static class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Configure logging
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole();
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        });

        // Configure the HttpClientHandler to support HTTP/3
        var httpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
            {
                EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls13
            },
            EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true,
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All,
            MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
        };
        
        httpHandler.SslOptions.ApplicationProtocols = new List<SslApplicationProtocol> { SslApplicationProtocol.Http3 };

        // Bypass certificate validation for testing (do not use in production)
        httpHandler.SslOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        // Create an HttpClient
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler)
        {
            // Set the base address to your server address
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7227")
        };

        // Create a gRPC channel
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(httpClient.BaseAddress, new GrpcChannelOptions
        {
            HttpClient = httpClient,
            LoggerFactory = loggerFactory,
            
        });

        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

        // Call the SayHello method
        var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "World" });

        Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);

        // Shutdown the channel
        await channel.ShutdownAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

The problem I am facing is, that the client is using HTTP/2 no matter what...
Packages used for the client:
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.64.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.65.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.27.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.2.0" />

Packages used for the server:
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.64.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />


HTTP/3 for TLS (SSL) is different from the httpclient using HTTP/3.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-http3#using-httpclient  You are missing DefaultRequestVersion =  HttpVersion.Version30

@jdweng: I followed the instructions on the provided link, but no success. Still using HTTP/2

How do you know it is HTTP/2?

Operating systems that support HTTP/3:

Windows: requires Windows 11 or Windows Server 2022.
Linux: Requires the latest version of OpenSSL and libcurl to support the QUIC protocol.
macOS: Requires macOS 12.3 or later.

